# Working with initial non-existent Field in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I need MongoDB to return a Zero value for an initial non-existent field in a certain record to prevent mongo from throwing the Error: the argument to $size must be an array but was of type: null...

I'm new to the aggregation framework, from my research $ifNull seem to be an option, but the truth is that I have tried using it in the aggregation, but I can't really figure how to implement it, all my use cases haven't been successful maybe because of the nature of the resulting aggregation I already have in place... I have already asked this question once but got no good response, and hope I won't be disqualified for asking again...

I have a collection wherein initially I have the following structure of user logged records

```
"_id": "5d6565236574b1162c349d8f",
        "name": "Micheal jackson",
        "department": "IT",
        "origin": "Texas",
        "employDate": "2019-08-27",
        "__v": 0,
```

And then, it is later updated like so :

```
 "_id": "5d6565236574b1162c349d8f",
        "name": "Micheal jackson",
        "department": "IT",
        "origin": "Texas",
        "employDate": "2019-08-27",
        "__v": 0,
        "attendances": {
            "2019-08-28": "Present"
        }
    },
```

// code to compute records for the last 30days

```
app.get('/api/employee/sumattendances',(req,res)=>{
  //sum attendances
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}


const listDatesForThePastDays = n => (
    Array(n)
        .fill(new Date())
        .map((today, i) => today - 8.64e7 * i)
        .map(formatDate)
)
```

// aggregation to the sum total "Present"  from the'attendances' field for the last 30 days.

```
    Employee.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "totalPresent": {
            "$sum": { 
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$attendances" },
                        "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$in": ["$$this.k", listDatesForThePastDays(30)] },
                                { "$eq": ["$$this.v", "Present"] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    } }
]).exec((err, results) => { if (err) throw err; res.json(results); })
})
```

At the point of creating a new record, the attendances field is non-existent, however, because the path to sum the total "Present" is called as soon as the application mounts, I need mongo to ignore the non-existent field and return a zero so that the application can keep running until the "attendances" field is created when the user performs an update

Comment: i guess, you can make `attendances` set to empty object. by making use of `$ifNull ` operator. and then proceed to the `$group`, in that case for those docs, which does not have `attendances` will be having it with empty object, and in `$group ` it wont fail.

Comment: @Saikat Chakrabortty I am not too familiar with the aggregation framework, could you please show a snippet, if you don't mind. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, you are performing the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation on those docs , which all are having field called `attendances`.

so you can simply put one pipeline stage [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/). inside that you can query for all those docs, in which `attendances` is exist, with [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). and the perform the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```
Employee.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { attendances: { $exists: true } }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalPresent: {
        $sum: {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$attendances" },
              cond: {
                $and: [
                  { $in: ["$$this.k", listDatesForThePastDays(30)] },
                  { $eq: ["$$this.v", "Present"] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).exec((err, results) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(results);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for!